# VMware won't work after Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: vmware, 15.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and now if I want to open VMware Player it doesn't do anything.
I also uninstalled and installed it again, still nothing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution below applies to versions of VMWare prior to 12.1.0.  The 12.1.0 version of VMWare does not require this fix.

---

VMWare and VMPlayer are in fact looking for a specific library string.  You can execute VMWare/VMPlayer from the terminal by executing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then `vmware` or `vmplayer`

I made this a permanent change on my system by executing instead

executing `sudo nano /usr/bin/vmware` and adding the line

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1`

after the line `export PRODUCT_NAME...`

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit:  VMWare will now work.

To perform the same function for VMPlayer, execute the same changes to `/usr/bin/vmplayer`

Comment: This is just a third party indicating that the above works. Be cautious of line breaks in the quoted commands. Also, have your key ready. It needed me to reenter my key. Fortunately, I still had that saved. Don't forget - if Charles helped you out, make sure you mark their answer as solving the problem.

Comment: @KGIII I didn't need to re-enter my key, although I do have it handy for those times I reinstall!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to accept the answer (assuming it did work for you). I'd been trying to figure out the same thing and had just figured I'd re-install later but then I saw your post and watched it. Fortunately Mr. Green has figured it out for us.

Comment: @KGIII I picked it up from a post in the vmware community forum actually - you can [read the post here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/518686)

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. I've noted the forum and will keep it bookmarked.

Comment: I tried what you said and I got this: http://i.imgur.com/IUHJ0Ok.png

Comment: @Lurrdock This is actually a separate problem, but VMWare requires several items to be present - this is its nice way of asking.  You will need to execute `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic` at a minimum.  I would suggest starting a new question about this.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution doesn't seem to be enough. I am able to launch wmplayer, then it asks me to compile and install several modules. When I authorize it, it gives me a lot of errors like (vmware-gksu:7071): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.

(vmware-gksu:7071): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

Comment: this worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/691715/vmware-player-on-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: @mango's link worked well for me. specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/694937/65046).