# Vmware Player doesnt start ubuntu 15.10

Tags: vmware, 15.10

I have an issue were vmware player doesnt start when i open it via the launcher. It just does nothing, no error message whatsoever. I got it running once, but now it wont open up.

Im using vmware 64 bit, already tried reinstall via the vmware installer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution below applies to versions of VMWare prior to 12.1.0. The 12.1.0 version of VMWare does not require this fix.

---

VMWare and VMPlayer are in fact looking for a specific library string.  You can execute VMWare/VMPlayer from the terminal by executing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then `vmware` or `vmplayer`

I made this a permanent change on my system by executing instead

executing `sudo nano /usr/bin/vmware` and adding the line

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1`

after the line `export PRODUCT_NAME...`

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit:  VMWare will now work.

To perform the same function for VMPlayer, execute the same changes to `/usr/bin/vmplayer`

Comment: is the vmware in the first code meant to be a seperate line? If so, that doesnt work. if I execute the path command and vmware after that it says "command not found".

Comment: In your case, execute `vmplayer` instead of `vmware`

Comment: it worked but now i cant open mysql workbench with this error: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11VariantTypeD1Ev

Comment: it looks a lot like this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1509729 
How can i reverse this?

Comment: That is actually a separate problem, and I'm one of the people that reported the bug you referred to (can't open gparted) - I have not looked into a work-around for this problem.

Comment: It used to work before I executed that line above, so that may be a reason for that kind of problem?

Comment: Really?  I hadn't noticed that myself, and I have heard other reports of the library issue.  Was it earlier today that you were able to run the sql workbench?

Comment: I can't recall if I tried earlier today, definitely worked on Friday though.

Comment: @Julian Are you running the first set of commands from the terminal, or the set of commands that created the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: I removed the file from my system, and then executed `sudo ldconfig` - now I can start gparted.  I assume that if you do the same, you can run sqlworkbench.  We may have to choose what we want to run...

Comment: @Julian I updated my answer:  remove the file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d if you created it, re-run `sudo ldconfig` and modiy your `/usr/bin/vmplayer` as noted in the answer

Comment: that worked, but i dont have /vmware just /vmplayer, other than that its fine, thanks!

Comment: I tryed this, but still have problems, could you please look at my question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/691715/vmware-player-on-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: Updating to vmware/player 12.1.0 seems to fix that without the workaround

Comment: @lviggiani This is quite true - the larger answer that this is a duplicate of indicates that as well.  I had forgotten to update this answer - please see my [other answer.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade/689135#689135)

Comment: Simple question please: where to write the `export` command in windows (I am on windows 10)?!

Comment: @Suda.nese I am unsure - I run  VMWare in Linux myself, and do not know of or follow the problems with running VMWare in Windows.  You could try the [VMWare community forums.](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/workstation/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[thread])