# vmware player on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: vmware, 15.10, vmware-player

I just uploaded to Ubuntu 15.10 and my vmware player is not working anymore.

I tried to follow the solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690336/vmware-player-doesnt-start-ubuntu-15-10) but it doesn't seem to be enough for me.

When I run `vmplayer` I get a lot of error messages like

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module": libunity-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(vmware-modconfig:9701): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

At this point it asks me to compile and load several module into the kernel. If I say `Install` it asks for my password and then gives some more errors like

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory             
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(vmware-gksu:9701): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.

(vmware-gksu:9701): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(vmware-gksu:9701): Pango-WARNING **: Failed to load Pango module '/usr/lib/vmware/libconf/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so' for id 'BasicScriptEngineFc'

(vmware-gksu:9701): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.

(vmware-gksu:9701): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

and then it quits.

What should I do to fix this? I quite a noob, so please try to be as detailed as possible.

UPDATE: If I try to run `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` the output is

```
Stopping VMware services:
VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
VM communication interface socket family                            done
Virtual machine communication interface                             done
Virtual machine monitor                                             done
Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1332:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlina
ble [-Wattributes]
LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
^
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/task.o
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function     ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:2054:1: warning: the  frame size of 1184 bytes is larger tha
n 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]

}
^
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC      /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build/include/..     SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/driver.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/hub.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/userif.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/netif.o
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2252:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
^
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/procfs.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/smac.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning:   "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
^
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2252:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c:50:0:
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function ‘VNetBridgeUp’:
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:81:40: error: too few arguments to function ‘sk_alloc’
#   define compat_sk_alloc(_bri, _pri) sk_alloc(&init_net, \
                                    ^
/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c:952:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘compat_sk_alloc’
bridge->sk = compat_sk_alloc(bridge, GFP_ATOMIC);
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/compat_sock.h:23:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.c:35:
include/net/sock.h:1515:14: note: declared here
struct sock *sk_alloc(struct net *net, int family, gfp_t priority,
          ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-    sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-sQDoPN/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Comment: How did you insall vmplayer, and what type of OS are you running?  Version info for linux can be found by executing `lsb_release -a`, and I am hoping you know which version of vmplayer you have

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 15.10, I just updated. Kernel version 4.2.0-16-generic. I have VMware Player 7.1.0 build-2496824

Comment: Ok - and the installation method for vmplayer?  You do seem to be missing a lot of something!

Comment: A couple of items that I'd like you to check:  Are you current on all the updates?  Does `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` indicate that any packages have not been installed?  Has a reboot been done recently?

Comment: Finally, I'd like to see you run `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` and capture the output, to post onto your question

Comment: @CharlesGreen I can't remember how I installed it, but I was on Ubuntu 15.04 or even 14.10. Surely I followed some provided instructions. The `apt-get` commands execute without problems. I updated the question with the output of the command you suggested

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for your support. I solved my issues just reinstalling the newest version of VmWare player and using the suggestion present in the other related questions

Answer (score 3):

(K)Ubuntu 15.10 with Kernel 4.2.0-17 and VMPlayer 7.1.2:

1. open a terminal, eg. Konsole
2. `cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source`
3. `sudo tar -xf vmnet.tar`
4. use your favorite text editor, eg. joe, to edit vmnetInt.h:

`sudo joe vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h`

5. in line 82, add a trailing ",1" just as in line 84

   old: `PF_NETLINK, _pri, &vmnet_proto)`

   new: `PF_NETLINK, _pri, &vmnet_proto, 1)`
6. save your changes and add them back into the tar:

`sudo tar -uf vmnet.tar vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h`

7. run vmplayer again, it should build now

`sudo vmplayer`

Comment: with Kernel 4.2.0-19 and VMPlayer 7.1.3 line 82 was already as described above.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did and it worked for me:

```
echo /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf
```

Then run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

So it will stick.

I manually modified my file in order for it to work for me, but found an easier way in the VMware community forums to share here: [Workstation 12 on Debian Linux host does not launch, no GUI no error messages.](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2546641#2546641)

Hope it helps , as it helped me ;-)

After this you should be able to still use your Icon in the Unity bar, or launch it from a terminal:

```
vmware
```

Comment: Have to add another comment.  Unfortunately, after doing the above, it caused other errors, which made several applications fail to load with symbol errors.  The above line echoed to that file was the only library listed in the file, which somehow made gnome-system-monitor and several other applications fail with symbol errors like the following: $ gnome-system-monitor
gnome-system-monitor: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11VariantTypeD1Ev

Comment: Putting the following in the /usr/bin/vmplayer file works and does not conflict with the rest of the system:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 2):

i tried doing the following for my Ubuntu 15.10
My specifications are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Shan-Ubuntu 4.2.0-19-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 11 11:39:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I firstly removed the VMWare Player previously installed using the following lines:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Then I reinstalled it from the website [VMWare Website](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0)
and since I had a problem of `canberra-gtk-module` I used:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

and once the download is done, in terminal I run:

```
vmplayer
```

with Gtk-Errors which can be completely ignored the VMplayer starts completely.

Hope this helps
Shan

Comment: After a couple of hours of really struggling getting VMware player to work after an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, this solution worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu Mate, based in Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 4.2.0-22-generic. It happened starting the player after a normal update & upgrade that included the base kernel. What worked for me was the simplest thing ever ... start 'vmplayer' as root, wait for the modules to compile and then close & open it with my normal user.

```
cguevara@xps:~$ vmplayer 

    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(vmware-gksu:12917): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.

(vmware-gksu:12917): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(vmware-gksu:12917): Pango-WARNING **: Failed to load Pango module '/usr/lib/vmware/libconf/lib/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so' for id 'BasicScriptEngineFc'

(vmware-gksu:12917): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.
```

Output after:

```
cguevara@xps:~$ vmplayer 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml"
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

[at this point is running again]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, nothing proposed helped.Then I uninstalled vmware player, and I downloaded and installed 12.0.1 version, allowed it to update to 12.1.0. Now it's working like a charm.