# Vmware Workstation 11 Virtual Ethernet Kernel update fails on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: kernel, vmware, 15.10

I'd appreciate some insight.  I've tried Charles's workaround here: [VMware won't work after Ubuntu Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade)  which passes the first hurdle and I get a Kernel upgrade message, but then it fails to update Kernel ... fails on Vmnetwork. Output of CLI below:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-TrwoH8/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-TrwoH8/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done

   Virtual machine communication interface                             done

   VM communication interface socket family                            done

   Blocking file system                                                done

   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed

   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

Comment: Saw your note here TonyM - I thought you were workstation 12...  Workstation 11 needs some patches to compile properly - they can be downloaded from github and run into your system.  [The github link](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches) has complete instructions.  There are also [some notes for kernel 3.19](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/03/03/how-to-patch-vmware-workstation-11-player-7-on-linux-3-19-kernels/) which are still applicable.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Yip, I did have WKS 11.  I used your fix for WKS 12 and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it doing.

after kernel 4.4 (VMWare Workstation 12) need some changes in c code:

/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

1) vmmon.tar

- untar
- change ./vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
- replace all:

  "get_user_pages" to "get_user_pages_remote"
- tar and replace original

2) vmnet.tar

- untar
- change ./vmnet-only/userif.c
- replace all:

  "get_user_pages" to "get_user_pages_remote"
- tar and replace original

Successful compiled on FC23 FC24, FC25 (kernel 4.7)

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2598402#2598402