# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and VMWARE Player (ver 4, 6, 12) all fail

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, vmware-player

I have been trying to get VMWare Player (any version) to run under Ubuntu 12.04 or above

I get multiple errors, I have been upgrading drivers and patches for 3 days from the net and I continue to get errors.  I have reinstalled 3 different version of Ubuntu and at least 5 different versions of VMWare - VMWare fails on startup after install every time - lots of different errors.

Can someone provide a version of Ubuntu and VMWare Player that work together?  It used to work fine on my 10.04 LTS 32 bit, but ever since I upgraded it hasn't worked and now I really need this functionality.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the current version of VMWare (12) and Ubuntu 15.10 quite well together.  There is a very small patch which needs to be added to the VMWare launch programs.  That can be found at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade/689135#689135)

Comment: I tried this, the first module loaded but then failed on startup, GTK module needed updating, as soon as I did that the first module failed so still not up - I am about to go over to the darkside, I just cannot get VMWare Player to run

Comment: Very strange - your system is fully updated?

Comment: Yes - new load and updated...I can't think of anything to add, I guess I could post my log file, but this isn't my first try.  What I found different this time is using the above patch the first module loaded sucessfully but the second failed, with the GTK driver, so I loaded the GTK driver and then the first module failed (that was previously successful).  I can't believe how unfriendly Ubuntu and VMWare are together now, they used to be easy to run.

Comment: It you open a terminal window, and issue the following two commands, do you receive any error messages?  First `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` followed by `vmware`