# VMware wont run in ubuntu 16.04 LTS (No Error msg even)

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-player, vmware-workstation

Downloaded VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.6-2700073.i386 bundle and installed it. Installer UI ran and gave installation successful message. But after that neither vmware nor vmplayer will run from the application. No error message, no window, nothing.

Tried [VMware won't work after Ubuntu Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade) solution, but didn't work either.It gave me  this box

[image]

saying "Several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel"-- then it prompted for admin password and thats it. No window, nothing. Haven't yet seen the EULA page of VMware. What can I do?

Comment: lol this is one of the main reasons I moved to VirtualBox and stopped using VMware. Every time there is an OS update VMware stops working and you have to wait for a patch or something so you can compile those modules it needs at the first run. As for your issue .. You will probably not be able to use that version of VMware anymore. You will need to update to 12 I think it is now .. and even 12 I couldn't get to work when I updated to 16.04. Maybe now they have that fixed but I gave up on VMware. I prefer a VM that works all the time not only after I "fix" it.

Comment: also .. I'm assuming you are running this on a very very old system? I noticed you are installing a 32 bit version. If you are running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu then you need to install the 64 bit version or you have to make Ubuntu be able to use 32 bit executables.

Comment: Another alternative to VMWare is KVM - I switched over about a year back.