# Windows XP in VMWare Player running HealTech OBD Tool will not connect to Motorcycle

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am running [VMWare Workstation 12 Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-for-linux.html) v12.5.0 build-4352439 with Windows XP SP3 in Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit v4.4.0-36-generic on a System76 Kudu Pro laptop.  I am using this to run the [HealTech OBD Tool](http://www.healtech-electronics.com/products/obd/), a USB-to-OBD adapter with Windows software.  The setup of VMWare, the Windows VMWare utilities, and the HealTech software all went fine.  The VMWare software detects the adapter, reading the HW version and serial number.  The USB connect icon flashes in the status bar of VMWare indicating a connection.  The device will not connect to the motorcycle when hooked up and selecting "Connect" in the software.  I cannot find any advanced settings in the player for USB connectivity, are there any Ubuntu settings that may have to be checked or optimized for use with VMWare?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in another question, "[VMware wont run in ubuntu 16.04 LTS (No Error msg even)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786029/vmware-wont-run-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-no-error-msg-even)".  Severus Tux recommended using VirtualBox instead of VMWare Player.  I installed VirtualBox, and with a little research got it running. OBD Tool now connects via the USB, and data can be read from our bikes.  VMWare may be able to work as well, and I would still like to try it if I figure out how to get it working.